# Register a Gaming Device

Tags: c++, python, c, windows

I have been looking at questions related to this, but cannot find a definite answer.

> How can I first register a device (programatically) as a Game pad/Joystick? And then pass the events (button clicks, analog displacement, etc)?

Also, then how would i make the Driver in `python` (I know that it is mainly written in `c` or `c++`, api accessible, i know that `win32api` might be useful.

What I have looked at, http://code.google.com/p/vmulti/.

API's:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You want to access a driver from python, or you want to make a driver with python?  The first is not too hard, if you control the driver.  The second is definitely not recommended.  Kernel mode code should be kept as simple as possible, since bugs bring down your entire computer.

Comment: @BenVoigt  just want to make a driver in any language to allow me to register a gamepad and then pass each button/axis data to the api.

Comment: Ok, well your basic approach will be this: 1 driver with two device instances.  One instance is a gamepad.  The other instance is a general device file.  The two will share memory, so that data written to the file is passed to the gamepad.  Then your python program can open the file (it will have a funny name like `\\.\Device\VirtualGamePadCtrl`) and write the button/axis data to it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I dont need to use python if not necessary. I just want to use 'c,c++' or anything except vbscript. I saw some api's for microsoft, but I just dont know how to initiate the driver. The button/axis data, I just want to send arrays. The doc here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Those APIs you linked to are the interface between the OS and applications listening to the gamepad data.  They are not the interface between the device driver supplying gamepad data and the OS.  But the `vmulti` project you linked to should demonstrate how to use the device->OS interface (one of them anyway, called "Human Interface Device", and one is all you need).

Comment: @BenVoigt Could you help me out and show me an example?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a fairly complex project and it's been years since I worked on something similar (modifying a hardware driver to inject test data).

Answer (score 2):

It's not the answer, but read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540521(v=vs.85).aspx

Use C(++) and it shouldn;t be that hard to solve. Reason I post this as an answer is as I can't seem to make a comment on the post above anymore.

Comment: Nice, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Since, the link you provided led me to formulate an answer, I will award you the bounty.